# Why should we manually tell the compiler covariance or contravariance?

Tags: c#

C# 4.0 introduced Covariance and Contravariance, and the keywords `in` and `out`.

But why do we have to be explicit about it? The compiler could have known it's OK if we pass a "SMALL" type to a "BIG" type, otherwise it gives an error itself.

And I find that it works intelligently in some other languages.

Such as in Salesforce apex code, I can write this without any error:

```java
List<object> a = new List<Integer>();
```

But in C# I can not do that, and you have to tell the compiler "in" or "out".

```cs
TResult Del<in T, out TResult>(T instance)
```

What I'm thinking is if the compiler can figure it out by itself, we can write less code.

For example.

```cs
delegate T Function<out T>();

static void Test()
{
    Function<Son> funcBar = new Function<Son>(GetInstance);
    Function<Person> funcFoo = funcBar; //the compiler knows I'm passing a small type to a big type, why it's necessary to tell it `out`
    Person foo = funcFoo();
}

static Son GetInstance()
{
    return new Son();
}

class Person
{

}
class Son : Person
{

}
```

Comment: I suggest you to read about covariance in detail. Then you'll understand what's wrong with `List<object> a = new List<Integer>()`. `List` should be invariant, since it provides both reads and writes, and therefore this line shouldn't be valid.

Comment: @dyukha No, that's not what I'm confused.

Comment: You can still do `IEnumerable<object> = new List<ReferenceType>()` for read-only access.

Comment: Then what's your question? You have to specify co-/contra-variance to say what kind of casts are valid. Otherwise there is a risk of dangerous cast, like the one with `List`.

Comment: Can you provide an example of where you believe the compiler should be able to infer usage ? Right now your examples don't give context to the problem.

Comment: `it works intelligently in some other languages.` C# is **not** some *other languages*, and the designers have take a very **caution** approach when designing C#, *generic type safety* and *static analysis* as to not add all the problems of said *other languages*. Embrace it, be the language, become the language... *waves his hands around in a mystic way*

Comment: I guess the compiler could infer that an interface is covariant when it finds that the interface never accepts `T` as a parameter, and could infer that an interface is contravariant if it does not have any methods that return a `T`. is that what you're asking, OP? Why doesn't it?

Comment: Okay I've edited my answer to address your example.

Comment: The terms are too opaque, type-safety is the concern here.  A statically typed language like C# needs to figure out at compile-time that an operation on a type cannot cause the code to crash.  In the given example, all it knows about `a` is that it contains elements of type System.Object.  But you should only be allowed to Add() an element of type Integer.  There is no practical way to enforce that, so the compiler doesn't permit it.  There are a few practical cases where this can still come to a good end, a simple in interface that only permits reading like IEnumerable for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is already mentioned in the comments but here is an example of why the first example shouldn't work,

```
List<object> a = new List<Integer>(); // <--- assuming this works

a.Add(new Integer()); // <--- works fine

a.Add(new object()); // <--- compiler would let this through but it is a logical error
```

The type of `a` is `List<object>` therefore the last statement is valid but it cannot work as the underlying implementation is of type `List<Integer>`. There is a valid scenario where

```
object b = new Integer()
a.Add(b) // <--- compiles and runs fine
```

But this `dangerous cast` (i.e. could be a runtime exception) should not be implicitly allowed by the framework but specified explicitly by the programmer.

**Delegates**

Delegates are no different, in fact `in` and `out` refer to input safety and output safety in any generic context be it collections or delegates.

With the `out` keyword

```
Function<Son> funcBar = new Function<Son>(GetInstance);
Function<Person> funcFoo = funcBar; // <--- output safety enables this
Function<Son> funcFooBar = funcFoo; // <--- output safety prevents this
```

The argument here is that a less specific function can always return a more specific type but a more specific function cannot return a less specific type. i.e. Son cannot return a Person because Son has more properties than a Person ever will, and trying to access Son properties on a Person object is a run-time exception unless the Person reference holds a Son object which you have to cast explicitly at your own risk.

With the `in` keyword

```
delegate void Func<in T>;
Func<Person> funcBar = (person) => person.Name = "John";
Func<Son> funcFoo = funcBar;         // <--- input safety enables this
Func<Person> funcFooBar = funcFoo;   // <--- input safety prevents this
```

The argument here is that a less specific function can modify a more specific object safely. I.e. a function that modifies a Person can also modify a Son as the Son is also a Person. But a function that modifies a Son cannot modify a Person because the Son has more characteristics (properties/members/fields) than a Person ever will and trying to modify a Son's properties on a Person object is impossible.

**The anwser**

Knowing this behaviour, the compiler cannot infer this information because the **compiler cannot assume anything about the concrete implementation of the generic type.** In fact, the compiler may not even see any implementation of the generic type at compile time, for eg: when building an external library.

What you have done here is looked at the concrete implementation of the generic and concluded the that the `out` parameter is not needed in the first place. Generics and other abstractions are a contract on how concrete implementations should behave in concrete types. The contract occurs first and the compiler uses this contract to judge implementations and make sure they are up to specification not the other way round.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry `List` type may be not a good example. Let me edit my question.

Comment: I chose you as the answer, but I still think we can talk more about this.

```c#
delegate T Function<T>();
delegate T Function<out T>();
```

Have a look at these two lines code.
Does line 2 tells more information than line 1 just in terms of language ?