# Converting object (List<string>) to List<object>

Tags: c#

Im trying to write a small framework for REST-API testing. Im using a lot of reflection and came to a problem I cant help myself.

Im using this line to extract a variable the user gives my as a path (string)

```
object o = input.GetType().GetProperty(name).propertyInfo.GetValue(input, null);
```

This object can be a normal type `T` or a `List<T>`.
Now if its a List and I know the type everything is simple, I can use

```
List<string> l = (List<string>)o; // I know its a List<string> because the user told me
```

To parse the object into the given array. But I dont always know the type of the objects in the list and

```
List<object> l = (List<object>)o; // I dont know the type and I dont care
```

gives me an error.

> Object of type "System.Collection.GenericList[System.String]" can not
>   be converted to "System.Collection.GenericList[System.Object]"

Is there anything I can do to receive the list of objects? I dont want the user to specify the type because its only the last variable I want to care about. Like

The user wants to test "object1.a.b.c" I only need to know the type of c, because thats where the test runs.

TIA

Comment: is there a particular reason you're using reflection over, say, `dynamic`? Ed: you mention specifically that you "don't know... don't care" about the type, hence why I ask about dynamic

Comment: Can't you do all this at the JSON level with JObjects and JTokens?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56388145/why-should-we-manually-tell-the-compiler-covariance-or-contravariance/56388347#56388347

Comment: @JoshE I use reflection mainly because I want the user to give me the "path" to the variable as a string, which allows me to put some extra syntax in like base.arr[x].i

Comment: @AvinKavish JSON level would be plan B. The main reason for not using JSON level is, because I want it to be "type-safe" and thus allow the user to use member-functions on the given variable he wants to test. Like ``test<myClass>("a.b.c", x => x.foo() > 5); // c is of type myClass``

Comment: @Narase In your example, how do you know what type `c` is going to be?

Comment: @AvinKavish Its because of the template. The algorithm takes an object and tries to find a member with the name 'a', then it tried to find a member with the name 'b', ... all the types are not of interest but c is of type ``T`` and thus can be converted and the test function can use the object with its real type

Comment: Yes but how would you know the type for the template if this is a user initiated action?

Comment: @AvinKavish I'm sorry feel like I can't follow you. The user sets up the tests so he knows the type of the variable he wants to test. He *could* also give the types for all the variables I need to pass to get to the last one, but I want to avoid that since it would mean to much writing

Answer (score 7):

You may convert it to `IEnumerable<object>`, but not `List<object>`.  The reason is: a list of bananas is not a list of fruit because you can put an apple into a list of fruit, but not into a list of bananas. Since the two types allow different operations, they are not compatible.

A sequence has no "put into" operation, so it is possible to use a list of bananas as a *sequence* of fruit. Similarly, you can use a list of strings as a *sequence* of objects, but not a *list* of objects.

This feature is called generic covariance; for more information, do a search on C# covariance and you'll find plenty of articles explaining how it works.

Note in particular that covariance only works on reference types; you may not use a sequence of integers as a sequence of objects. Do you see why?

Alternatively, if you have an `IEnumerable` in hand, you can make a *copy* of *any* sequence into a list of objects with `mysequence.Cast<object>().ToList()`. But this is a copy, not a reference conversion.

Comment: Does the "special" case of String/string have special behavior in this regard due to their value type/reference type duality?

Comment: @JoshE: I have no idea what you're talking about. Can you explain in more detail? I suspect you have a very wrong belief about reference types, and we should dispel that wrong belief.

Comment: sorry for the ambiguity; I know that covariance applies to strings the same way it would apply to any other reference type, ~~. ed: I *am* a bit rusty on string/value type mechanics -immutability != value type

Comment: @JoshE: Under what circumstances can "strings be treated as value types"?  Strings are *compared by value* because they override `Equals`; is that what you're thinking of?

Comment: yeap, that's what I was thinking of, the value comparison of a reference type. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @JoshE: Got it. Covariance does not affect equality comparisons, nor is it affected by them. (Though, interestingly, `IComparable<T>` is *contravariant* which is sometimes useful.)

Answer (score 1):

Since your problem begins at processing dynamic objects that arrive as JSON to the server, it's quite convenient to use the JSON Processing library itself to test for certain characteristics before converting to POCOs. Using newtonsoft's JSON.Net,

```
var o = JObject.Parse(json);
JToken property = o["a"]["b"]["c"];
if (property != null)
{
    if (property.Type == JTokenType.Array)
    {
      // Process property as array

    }
    else if  (property.Type == JTokenType.Object)
    {
      // Process property as object
    }
    // Magnitude of other types
}
```

I do understand the need to convert to .NET types before final processing but I would highly recommend beginning with JObjects as the library is designed for this purpose and provides numerous convenience methods for many dynamic operations that C# doesn't provide natively.

- [JToken Type Reference](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JTokenType.htm)
- [JObject Class](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm)